# Meaning of animal names examples

Tags: grammar-dikduk

We always say that animals were named by Adam based on their tasks or essence in life. The famous example is that the word for dog, כלב, comes from כ-לב, meaning “like a heart.” So the drash is that dogs are man’s best friend
This is the example everyone always gives when talking about this subject. But what other examples are there? What are animal names reflect their essences?

Comment: What's the source for the dog one?

Comment: @shmosel idk I’ve just heard it so many times

Comment: @shmosel - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65589/22152